# Excel VBA: Error Handling with Case Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to validate a file that is uploaded by the user using the code below. The error handler checks the top row of the uploaded file for three specific column names. If one or more of the column names is not present, the program should return a prompt to the user notifying them which column(s) are missing from the file that they uploaded and then close the file.

There are a couple issues with my current VBA code that I am seeking help with:

1. The prompt doesn't specify which column(s) are missing to the user.
2. The error handler is triggered even when all required columns are present in the uploaded file.

Code:

```
Sub getworkbook()
' Get workbook...
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filter As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    filter = ".xlsx,.xls"
    caption = "Please select an input file "
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

On Error GoTo ErrorLine:

'Check for columns
var1 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("variable1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Column
var2 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("variable2", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Column
var3 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("variable3", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Column

ErrorLine: MsgBox ("The selected file is missing a key data column, please upload a correctly formated file.")
If Error = True Then ActiveWorkSheet.Close

wb.Sheets(1).Move Before:=targetWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet2")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a good use case for using error handling: missing column headers can be detected and are sort of "expected" (at least in some cases).  You should reserve error handling for cases where something unexpected happens (a file cannot be found or opened for example).  Scott's answer below shows a better approach to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

How about this AME. Should do everything you want and alert the users which data columns are missing. Also, no need for `GoTo` statements. Just a simple `If Then Else`

```
Sub getworkbook()
' Get workbook...
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filter As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    filter = ".xlsx,.xls"
    Caption = "Please select an input file "
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

    'Check for columns
    Dim var1 As Range, var2 As Range, var3 As Range
    Set var1 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("variable1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Column
    Set var2 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("variable2", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Column
    Set var3 = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("variable3", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Column

    If Not var1 Is Nothing Or Not var2 Is Nothing Or Not var3 Is Nothing Then

        wb.Sheets(1).Move Before:=targetWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet2")
        ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA"

    Else

       MsgBox "The selected file is missing the following key data column(s): " & _
        vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & _
        IIf(var1 Is Nothing, "variable1", "") & _
        IIf(var2 Is Nothing, "variable2", "") & _
        IIf(var3 Is Nothing, "variable3", "") & _
        vbNewLine & _
        "Please upload a correctly formated file."

        ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott - is that Msgbox line correct?  It would only show column names which are found...

Comment: I am getting an error when the program gets to the Var1. "Object variable or with block variable not set". Should this varible be defined as a range?

Comment: I have to fix the message box code. Hang in there, I am doing it now. That should solve your issue.

Comment: @TimWilliams -> I knew my haste would come back to bite me in the @ss! Thanks for the check-up.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I am still getting the same error as mentioned before.

Comment: Heh @ScottHoltzman you don't have error handling for if those methods don't return successfully with `Find` since you are also trying to get the column from them instead of checking if they are nothing, first ;)

Comment: @AME - remove the `.Column` reference at the end of each `varX` set. Then it should work like a charm. Trying to get the column number is not needed for this code.

Comment: did you dimension the variables as ranges? If so, can you post a link to your data sheet? I can probably help you better if I see some data (can be dummy data, of course).

Answer (score 0):

see if this is what you want

```
Sub getworkbook()
    ' Get workbook...
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filter As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    filter = ".xlsx,.xls"
    Caption = "Please select an input file "
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)



'Check the headers in first row
Dim width As Long
Dim var1 As Long, var2 As Long, var3 As Long
With ActiveSheet
    width = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' getting the non-empty columns from right to left scanning
    ' var1,2,3 will store the column number contains variable1,2,3
    var1 = -1
    var2 = -1
    var3 = -1
    For j = 1 To width
        If .Cells(1, j).Value = "variable1" Then
            var1 = j
        ElseIf .Cells(1, j).Value = "variable2" Then
            var2 = j
        ElseIf .Cells(1, j).Value = "variable3" Then
            var3 = j
        End If
    Next j


    If var1 = -1 Then
        MsgBox "variable1 not found"
    End If
    If var2 = -1 Then
        MsgBox "variable2 not found"
    End If
    If var3 = -1 Then
        MsgBox "variable3 not found"
    End If
End With


wb.Sheets(1).Move Before:=targetWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet2")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA"

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicity end the Sub processing if no errors ocurred, putting an `Exit Sub` statement just before the `ErrorLine` block declaration. It should address the undesired triggering issue.